# dplyr equivalent for in

Tags: r, dplyr

How would I write a dplyr statement that behaves like the `in` would in a SQL query.

Example in SQL

```
SELECT name
FROM Person
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM Worker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`library(dplyr)`

person %>% select(name) %>% filter(name %in% Worker$name)
```

I actually don't know what the datasets look like so this is 100% hunch.

Comment: Could also do an inner join